# Forms Authentication loginURL not redirecting to root Default.aspx after timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an application where the root Default.aspx page is the login page. Logging 
into the application works properly, and all other web pages are in subdirectories. Once on a subdirectory page, if the application times out, the application should return back to the root directory default.aspx for re-login. Instead it is trying to call a default page in the subdirectory which doesn't exist. Ex: /subdirA/subdirB/Default.aspx, when it should try to run just Default.aspx. Following is what I have in my web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="/Default.aspx" timeout="10"/>
</authentication>
```

I have also tried "~Default.aspx", "~/Default.aspx", and "Default.aspx" none work.
I found some hints to add the following to appSettings:

This did not work either. Am at a loss, any help is appreciated!

**Update**
It looks like my application isn't using the loginUrl at all. I made a dummy front page for default.aspx, and moved the login page to /login/login.aspx, and changed the loginUrl to /login/login.aspx. Logged into the app and went to a page in a subdirectory, and let it timeout. It still tries to go to /subdirA/subdirB/Default.aspx.  Why would it not use the loginUrl at all?

Comment: What happens if you explicitly logout from one of the sub-directory pages? Also, have you ensured that there is no redirect in place?

Comment: It looks like my application isn't using the loginUrl at all. I made a dummy front page for default.aspx, and moved the login page to /login/login.aspx, and changed the loginUrl to /login/login.aspx. Logged into the app and went to a page in a subdirectory, and let it timeout. It still tries to go to /subdirA/subdirB/Default.aspx. Why would it not use the loginUrl at all?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue - there was a redirect in the masterpage that was not working correctly. Changed this to ~/Default.aspx and is now working properly.